# Lost in translation: Pluma ibérico

Tags: pork, language

In Spain,there are three popular iberian pork cuts: Secreto (or Cruceta), Bola (or Presa or Abanico) and Pluma. I have a question about the 'pluma' that I can probably ask without referring to the specific cut, but I'd like to know if there is an accepted translation.

These cuts are extra tender and delicious because of the grease content. Butchers used to get rid of these cuts because of that. Some used to eat the meat themselves, it was the butcher's 'secret'. The 'pluma' is also called the butcher's steak(?).

There's a story in [Spanish here](http://www.elespeciero.net/2008/04/el-secreto.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell the "pluma" consists of the cervical and thoracic rhomboid muscles.  Those muscles are not standard cuts in the US.  It would likely remain attached to the whole loin or as part of blade end loin chops.

The article you linked to states that "the pluma should not be confused with the blade end of the loin or the 'butcher's filet' which is the caudal (tail-ward) cut of the loin."

There is a video on how the pluma is butchered available on youtube: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3H_HNjStwsk

Comment: Welcome to the site, Drew. I look forward to seeing more answers of you.